# How do I properly protect my webserver from spoofed requests?

Tags: security, web, hash, server, client

I apologize if this question is vague or has been asked before - I don't know enough about what I'm trying to ask in order to search for an answer.

I am creating a backend server for a game that responds to HTTPS requests. This game is rather simple at this point - you have some stats and an inventory that can be checked and modified in various ways. I want to create a web interface for this, that would allow you to perform a few important actions that involve modifying your character data (leveling up, assigning stat points, managing inventory, etc.) However, I have a concern! I am worried about people taking a peek at the source code for this web page, piecing together the commands that would, for example, add a point to a statistic or an item to your inventory, and then "spoof" that command to my server, allowing them to unfairly modify their character data.

the HTTPS request to add an item to your inventory might look like this (imagine it as an onClick for a button or something):

```
<button onClick=makeRequest("mydomain/characters/myCharacterName/add_inventory?Stick=1")>Get Stick</button>
```

You can see how it would be trivial to pick this piece of code apart and use it in other ways. How can I provide this sort of functionality in a web page, without giving away the ability to exploit it? I have considered a few options, none of which seem like they would work. I feel like the answer might have to do with including a hash of the request as a redeemable "token" of sorts, but I am not sure. Any input on this would be greatly appreciated, as I am sure it is a rather fundamental concept that will help me now and in the future.

Comment: Shouldn't there be a logic in the server side that knows what operations are possible -- and therefore it would not be possible to do anything else.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should authenticate all requests to your website using an authentication mechanism such as [JSON web tokens](https://jwt.io/).

You should also secure your web server by validating all input such as url parameters. If your web server accesses a database server, then it should use prepared SQL queries. This should protect your server against SQL injection.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. After learning about JWTs, I was able to understand enough of the issue to find more on the topic. The specific vulnerability I am concerned about is called a 'replay' or 'playback' attack. It can be combatted by introducing some 'stateful' measures such as preventing duplicate tokens from being redeemed through the use of a token identifier (or JTI if using JWTs), combined with a method of including a timestamp in the token and having the server only accept tokens issued after a certain period. A stateless solution would be nice, but there doesn't seem to be one.